# How do I create a testing instance of my NodeJS app hosted on Azure Cloud Services?

Tags: node.js, azure

My client has a Node app running on Azure as a Cloud Service and using an Azure-hosted MS-SQL database. They would like another instance of the app running which they could use for testing changes before deployment to the production site. This instance would also have a separate database so that testing would not interfere with the live database. What is the most straightforward way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either create another cloud service to deploy your testing app, or use the staging slot of the cloud service you are using now. And create another database for test purpose.